# Zoom animation and XAML clutter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I am quite new to WPF, so pardon me for the noob question...

I implemented an old style "button clicked" animation that works with the Scale transforms:

```
    <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="PressableImage">
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard >
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" From="1" To="0.9" Duration="0:0:0.03" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" From="0.9" To="1" BeginTime="0:0:0.03" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" From="1" To="0.9" Duration="0:0:0.03" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" From="0.9" To="1" BeginTime="0:0:0.03" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

In order to make it work on my Image objects I need to declare them this way:

```
<Image x:Name="E00" Style="{StaticResource PressableImage}" Source="Resources/0.png" MouseDown="ClickMainMenu">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

I wanted to put the RenderTransform  section in the style definition, like I did with RenderTransformOrigin, but the only way I managed this to work was putting a RenderTransform definition in each Image definition...

Is there a way to put that inside the style definiton?

Answer (score 2):

In your question, I don't see any issue with setting the value via the style:

```
<Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="PressableImage">
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard >
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" From="1" To="0.9" Duration="0:0:0.03" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" From="0.9" To="1" BeginTime="0:0:0.03" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" From="1" To="0.9" Duration="0:0:0.03" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" From="0.9" To="1" BeginTime="0:0:0.03" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I get an exception:

'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll

'Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception.' Line number '145' and line position '24'.

Comment: @OrfQuarenghi Hm, works fine for me. Take a look at [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/14/108728.aspx) website about debugging `XamlParseException`.